# Why is $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am not very much familiar to calculate the $\operatorname{Tor}$ functor of $\operatorname{Tor}$ group. I need help in the following calculation, which I saw in the proof of Theorem 7.7 in Matsumura's book.

Let $M$ be a $A$-module and $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of $A$ such that $I \otimes M \to M$ is injective and $I \otimes_AM \to A \otimes_AM$ is injective. We have the short exact sequence $0 \to I \to A \to A/I \to 0$. **To show that** $$\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A)=0.$$
The logic in the sources is as follows:

The short exact sequence $0 \to I \to A \to A/I \to 0$ induces the long exact sequence $$0=\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A) \to \operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I) \to I \otimes M \to M \to \cdots,$$ since $I \otimes M \to M$ is injective.

I did not understand why $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A)=0.$

Please explain it and also if possible some further hints or tips to calculate $\operatorname{Tor}$.

Comment: Tor can be computed using a projective resolution of the second argument. But $A$ is projective as a $A$-module, so all higher Tor vanish.

Comment: In simpler terms: $A$ is flat over itself, since tensoring with $A$ is basically the identity functor.

Comment: @Roland, yes using projective resolution, I heard about it. But what do you mean by the word higher? Do you mean $i \geq 1$ ?

Comment: @CaptainLama, how the argument $I \otimes M \to M$ helping here?

Comment: It doesn't. Probably the correct statement was "$\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I)=0$".

Comment: @CaptainLama, no, it is not that. This is the proof of Theorem $7.7$ in Matsumura's book

Comment: Well, I'm looking at it, and it does seem like the goal is to show that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I)=0$. Which makes sense since $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A)=0$ is trivial, with no hypotheses needed.

Comment: @CaptainLama, your argument is correct that $A$ is flat over itself, so $Tor_i^A(M,A)=0$. But why then he used the above injective argument?  Well, how the injective argument help to show $Tor_i^A(M,A/I)=0$ ?

Comment: The projectivity of $A$ yields immediately that $\text{Tor}_1^A(A, M)=0$, so it seems extremely likely that the author intends to show that $T:=\text{Tor}^A_1(A/I, M)=0$. This follows from the exactness of the sequence. The image of $T\to I\otimes_AM$ must be trivial, as it is the kernel of the injection $I\otimes_AM\to M$, but then $T$ is the kernel and hence equal to the image of $0\to T$, thus giving $T=0$.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri, nice and reasonable and helpful comment

Comment: Thanks. That is also the only reasonable interpretation of what Matsumura-sama is intending.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri would you care to turn these comments in to an answer? For the OP, please please please include context (like where you saw this) in your questions - do note that your concerns were resolved as soon as someone was aware of the source of this.

Comment: @KReiser done :)

Comment: @KReiser, thank you for your nice suggestion and for editing  my question to give it a perfect form. Though I mentioned it in the comment section but I should have mentioned it in the question body

Comment: This is not "a perfect form", it's just meeting basic expectations. [Including context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) is important for all questions on this website - please do this _from the beginning_ on your future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projectivity of $A$ yields immediately that $\text{Tor}^A_1(A,M)=0$, so it seems extremely likely that the author intends to show that $T:=\text{Tor}^A_1(A/I,M)=0$. This follows from the long exact sequence of Tor. The image of $T→I\otimes_AM$ must be trivial, as it is the kernel of the injection $I\otimes_AM\to M$, but then $T$ is the kernel and hence equal to the image of $0\to T$, thus giving $T=0$. This is the only reasonable interpretation of the author's intent.